# AWS DNS alias for VPC local resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

I'd like to be able to provide a resource `SRV` that lives in two different VPCs.  So I'd give them DNS names `srv.vpc1.corp.com` and `srv.vpc2.corp.com`.

What I'm trying to figure out is if I can provision a `srv.corp.com` which always goes to the in-VPC destination?  That is, requests in vpc1 will always go to `srv.vpc1.corp.com`, and requests in vpc2 will always go to `srv.vpc2.corp.com`.

Route53 does have latency related routing but that doesn't appear to be able to guarantee the result will be local to the VPC.  Route53 can have private zones per VPC but they can't overlap at the domain level.  I could get another domain name or use `corp.local` per VPC, but that would require changing existing lookups.

Are there any other possibilities to make this work?

Comment: You should be able to create a private hosted zone in each VPC.

Comment: @Tim I looked into that but I'd have to duplicate the entire zone for each VPC.  That would be do-able but unpleasant.

Comment: Using CloudFormation infrastructure as code, with a single condition, you can deploy to two accounts in no time. Plenty of examples of Route53 hosted zone CloudFormation online. If you're deliberately duplicating your DNS you're going to have duplication.